# Android update imageview drawable in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, refresh, imageview

I'm trying to update my image view drawable after I download the images over internet in broadcast receiver. It's kinda lazy loading, but i have to download all the text data which takes a little longer and after that I need to download the images and show replace the default card and put them in image view. For now it's working, but I'm refreshing the whole activity when I receive an image. But I need to refresh only the imageview and show the new image. Any suggestions/ideas or something like that which can help me are welcomed!

Comment: ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle(); or invalidateSelf() ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) on the ImageView.

Comment: But when I should call that. I mean I'm using custom baseadapter and in it's getView method I'm setting the drawable to imageview. But how can I call adapters getview again?